# Google tags does not show up in Google Tag Assistant but it shows in GTM and Analytics' debug

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am new to all of this and am trying to install the GTM tag on my WordPress website. I tried the plugin Google Tag Manager for WP and later in Google Site Kit.

In both methods, I can only see the tags through Tag Assistant when logged in WordPress. If I log off from wp-admin and access the website, I can't see the tags.

When trying to use the debug on GTM it shows the Analytics tag was fired and when using Analytics debug I can see the events are happening:

1. Are my tags properly installed or not?
2. Why I can't see it in Tag Assistant or what do I need to do?
3. Is it better to install directly to the code without using a plug-in?

[Analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw5dC.png)

[GTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaPrw.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, it seems you did not publish your GTM container. But this is all I can see from your post. Let me know, when you checked this thing. Or show me you Publishing history in GTM.

Comment: @JakubKriz Thank you for the reply. I had published the container. Anyway, the tag started to show after a few hours. I didn't do anything and for some reason, it appears normally now.

Comment: Hi, I am happy it works for you now. Maybe the is a problem with your local cache. Try Ctrl+F5 for hard refresh when it happens again.